# Should the [astral] tag be renamed to [astral-plane]?

Tags: discussion, tags, rename-request

This seems like a pretty straightforward suggestion.

The [astral](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/astral) tag is currently used on just 5 questions, four of them about D&D 5e and one about 3.5e. In addition, all 5 questions are specifically about the Astral Plane. (There are quite a few other questions about the Astral Plane that don't have the tag; most of them do have the [planes](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planes) tag.)

**Should the [astral](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/astral) tag be renamed to [astral-plane](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/astral-plane)?**

Comment: The tag info has also now been edited to describe the Astral Plane as used in Shadowrun. This probably warrants its own meta, but it seems like the Astral Plane in Shadowrun is very different. There are a few questions without the tag that involve the Astral Plane/Astral Projection in Shadowrun... If we want a tag to cover those, this tag may need to be split into two (i.e. edit out the Shadowrun info and tag the appropriate questions as [astral-plane-sr] or something).

Comment: We don't do "game specific" tags, tags can be used in combination with other tags.

Comment: @mxyzplk: I know, but generally tags should refer to one (broad) type of thing, should they not? If one game uses "Astral Plane" to refer to one concept, and another game uses "Astral Plane" to refer to an almost totally different concept, is it appropriate to use the same tag name for both? Seems like it'd get confusing quick.

Comment: No, because as I said tags can be combined.  shadowrun+astral is different from D&D+astral.  the definition in that game isn't relevant to the "find it by a tag" need.

Answer (score 6):

## No

Especially in infrequently used tags, more general is better.  "Well my question isn't quite about the astral *plane* it's about..." is the immediate issue from the next question about astral phenomena. And then we have a fistful of astral tags all running the risk of deletion because they don't have enough use.

It is fit for use right now.  "I have a question about astral projection, or astral travel, or monsters on the astral plane, or whatever... I start typing in astral... Oh look there it is, great."  If you are searching for info on the astral plane, and you go to tag:astral, you're not exactly overwhelmed with 100s of superfluous questions.

Our tagging is not a logical taxonomy.  It is an emergent folksonomy, where it modifies to fit real needs and real numbers of questions, not a sense of logical rigor.

There are no problems with the existing tag, and none cited in the question, therefore no action should be taken. (By problem, I mean things that are affecting its usefulness in practice for questioners or answerers.)

Answer (score 0):

## Sure

Since they're all about the Astral Plane, it makes sense to me that the tag should be more specific to that. I don't know what "Astral" might mean outside of that context, but as it stands, if that ever did become relevant to a different context, it might then need to be split into [astral](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/astral) and [astral-plane](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/astral-plane), so might as well do that now.

I remember a similar question about renaming tags, and a diamond mod (doppelgreener/spooker, I think) mentioned that if they do it, they won't bump up all the questions. On the other hand, it's only a few questions, so it probably wouldn't matter if a non-mod user updated it...

Comment: Sidenote: Astral Plane is not only used in D&D, but also in Shadowrun (Though more common is Astral Space).

Comment: I found the tag as "Astral" and added a description. It could be "Astral Plane", "Astral Projection", or "Astral Travel"; However, they all involve the Astral Plane so I don't see a reason not to be more descriptive.